# Delphi - Network ODBC Database (MS Access)

Tags: database, delphi, ms-access, networking

I have a Database program which uses MS Access. The time has come and I need to make it a client/server app. The idea behind the scheme is: Server holds the database, and one or multiple clients need to access it simultaneously. The program will still need to operate under Ms Access (because porting DB and rewriting the app is out of the question).

Also another scheme which to be honest I don't really like is for the clients to request the DB file from the server, transfer it via LAN and access it locally... but Clients can make changes to it so it is ineffective.

Now my question is: Which is the proper way to implement this. And how to access the networked database? Make it shared, or is there any way using Indy and such.

Comment: I have read all the answers and still don't understand your question. Some of the answers assume you're using Access as a front end, which then raises the question of what Delphi is doing in the mix. I think you mean you're using a Jet MDB, and Access is not involved at any level, and when you say "The program will still need to operate under Ms Access (because porting DB and rewriting the app is out of the question)" you mean that you need to use the Jet production back end while developing your new app that uses a server back end. But it's not at all clear to me what your scenario is.

Comment: The Delphi app manipulates the database. It uses Delphi's standard ADO components, to access a MDB database. Til now the database was stored locally. Now the application needs to reside on another PC, and it will be still used to manipulate the DB, however other clients should connect to it and also alter the database ( not much though ).

And the question was "Which is the proper way to do this". 

The rewriting part means that porting it to a DB system incompatible with ADO is not a valid solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To share an access database, just place the *.MDB file into a network share and open it across the network.  I use this technique for up to around 15 network users, going beyond that or locations with a lot of traffic, I push to SQL Server.

Migration to SQLServer is a very easy task, especially if your using the dbGO components (ADO) as all that will be required is changing the connection string to point to the SQL Server instance.  The only issue I had with such a conversion was with boolean fields.  In access these fields have an internal representation of 0 or -1, and in SQL Server they have an internal representation of 0 or 1.  In Access they resolve as boolean, in SQL Server they do not.  For instance the following query fails in SQL Server:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE BOOLFIELD
```

it has to be rewritten as:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE BOOLFIELD <> 0
```

All of my other queries work properly...with the exception of date/time, which I suggest passing as parameters and letting the driver handle the translation.

The conversion process is fairly simple.  Use the migration tool to migrate your access database to SQL Server, then use the SQL Server script database to generate a script for you.  Either give this script to your customers to deploy, do it yourself at each location, or write a program to parse and execute each command as read from the file.

You can migrate data from one database to another via SQLServer using the [OpenDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179856.aspx) method and then performing an insert into from your access database.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE FROM 
  OpenDataSource('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0','Access.mdb')...TABLE
```

Another option would be to go n-Tier.  If you have the enterprise version of Delphi, then its not to hard to migrate the system over to a true n-Tier solution using TClientDatasets and writing a few server functions.  Of course mileage will depend much on the current layout of your application, and how complex the system is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll try the network version.

Since the clients wont give much traffic to the server, what they will have to do is insert a row into a table, alter a few existing rows and of course query stuff from 3 tables which by the way the three of them summed in 99% of the cases will not have more than 150 rows. If this fails, I'll strongly consider MSSQL.

Comment: There also is a client limit to consider with Access.  you can only have 255 connections to the database, in reality I don't recommend to my customers to use Access for more than 20 users, but thats my application... you might be able to get away with more.

Comment: Usually there will be one connected client, rarely 2 or 3. So i think 255 connections is OK. But i have already started messing around with the MS SQL with the possible upgrade in the future.

Answer (score 1):

File-based databases like Access are inherently single user. You can share them, but you are opening yourself up to a world of corrupt databases and pain. If you have  a multi-user application, you need a multi-user, server-based database.

Comment: Completely wrong. Access databases are inherently multi-user -- it's built into the foundation of Jet. If you know what you're doing to distribution the application and data portions appropriately, it will be very safe and reliable for a small workgroup user population (c. 25 users) and if you write your app well, up to as many as 100 users.

Comment: As someone who knows what she's doing and isn't exactly an SQL newbie, Access applications I've worked on become unstable after 10 concurrent users, unusable after 20 concurrent users. There's no reasonable way to serve an Access database to 100 users, unless you can guarantee that very few are connected at once, or you use mapped tables pointing to a better database system.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: try not to be such an Access fanboy. It has it's place, but with more than a handful of users it's not reliable. As a front end for, say, SQL Server, it's useful. It's a file format, not an engine in the sense of "send query, get results". Data is copied locally, locks stay on the network etc. Pulling the plug out of a client PC is liable to corrupt the network copy. You can't reliably back it up. etc etc

Comment: @Juliet: The fact that you've worked on Access apps that were so badly written that they couldn't run with more than 10 users doesn't in any way support the assertion that Access can support only one user, which is what this answer asserts in its first sentence. Whether or not you can support 100 users depends on what those users are doing interacting with the file, and how your front end engineer is implemented. With unbound data editing forms, you can support lots of users, but going unbound rather misses the point of using Access. I certainly recommend upsizing when headcount exceeds 15-20.

Comment: @gbn: How is correcting a misstatement of fact "being a fanboy"? This answer begins with a factually incorrect statement. I pointed that out, and expanded on that by mentioning real-world user populations. It is simply untrue to assert that "with more than a handful of users [Access] is not reliable." You have to be doing just about everything wrong (like not splitting your app and having multiple users open it simultaneously) for there to be problems. I know perfectly well the way Jet/ACE works as compared to a server database -- I probably know far, far more about that than you do, in fact.

Comment: ...And the reason I come into these threads and correct the record is that there are hordes and hordes of people who haven't a clue about how to use Access/Jet/ACE correctly and because of their ignorance, they've run into terrible problems. You can make a mess of SQL Server, too, if you do everything wrong, but the reason that doesn't often happen is because it's not nearly as accessible or easy to use as Access. As long as there are anti-Access bigots spreading misinformation about Access/Jet/ACE (as in the first sentence of this particular answer) I'll be correcting them.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using database with Delphi's ODBC control, you don't need to worry about porting AP and DB(well, maybe some minor issue to fix). ODBC makes all DB using same interface, so you can simply change Data Source Name (DSN) connection string to a remote server with acc/pw to login, and then everything should work. Also it may work fine even if you change Access to other ODBC system, like MySQL, with just few minor SQL command changes.

So back to your question. Using file on server will definite fail when your user grows for larger than, well, 2. On multiple user accessing database simultaneously, you will need the transaction (or atomic) behavior in the DB side, which is lacked in Access. Only a real DB server like MySQL or MSSQL or Oracle/DB2/... can do that.

Don't share the single database file. Use a real Database server, unless you only have one client.

Answer (score 0):

Why would porting the DB necessarily involve rewriting the application?

How about using the [SQL Server Migration Assistant](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/migration.aspx) to migrate your MS Access  Database to SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

My solution: Use something like RemObjects SDK to define an interface that applications call to get the data from the database. You probably have a datamodule or something that already defines the calls needed, but it can help tidy your app. Then you can access the data remotely using your app, and still access the Access database. When it suits, you can migrate the data to something else and not have to change the clients at all as they are now using the interface and don't care about the implementation.

They also do a remote data access system, but I shy away from that as it doesn't fit my needs. May be worth a look though.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime moving from one DB to another is very easy.
I migrate from Access to Firebird very easily (I think Firebird is [better](http://www.itexto.net/devkico/?p=398) than MySQL for Delphi)

The tools I use : http://www.clevercomponents.com/products/dbcomparer/dbcomparer.asp

Answer (score 0):

If your users are distributed widely around the Internet and you don't want to use a file share, one option is to use [EQL Data](http://eqldata.com/) to keep multiple copies of the database in sync.  It also helps publish the tables on the web.

Answer (score 0):

I was checking MSSQL Server and both 2005 and 2008 required the .NET framework to work. What other database systems which are compatible with ADO are available (not file based DB)